# Pasar un valor de un script a php

Tags: php, jquery

Tengo la siguiente función:

```
function distribucion_referencia(value)
    {

             var pago_total=cantidad_pagar_total.value;
             alert(pago_total/value);
             var pago_fracción = "" + (pago_total/value);
             $("#cantidad_rb_1").text(pago_fracción);
     ...}
```

La cantidad que se encuentra en  `pago_fracción` la quiero imprimir en un `input` como cantidad monetaria, solo que no puedo pasar ese dato al `PHP`.

Comment: Explica mejor que es lo que tienes y que quieres hacer.

Comment: Si en el HTML tienes un input cuyo id sea `myInput` si pones esto dentro de la función: `$('#myInput').val(pago_fraccion);` tendrás en él el valor de `pago_fraccion`  cuando la función se ejecute.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer es del JavaScript pasarlo a un input de HTML y de HTML a PHP mediante un form. Acá un ejemplo:

```
<?php 
 $valor = $_POST['valor']; //Recibes el valor del input mediante su nombre.
 ?>

 <form method="post">
    <input type="number" name="valor" id="valor"> <!-- Input donde setearás el valor -->
    <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
 </form>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    function darvalor (){ //La función debes iniciarla en alguna parte.
        var valor = 1;
        document.getElementById('valor').value = valor ; //Con este código debes buscar el input por su id y seguidamente setearle su valor.
    }
 </script>
```